# How to write a 2D array to csv for each frame of an image?

Tags: python, csv, numpy

I have a `getX()` which gives a 2D `array(shape=(18,2))` as an output for each frame of an image. I want to add this continuously updating array to the CSV.

I have used the following code. But it is giving me only one row *(probably for only one frame)*.

```
with open("data.csv",mode ='w') as csvfile:
            wr = csv.writer(csvfile, quoting = csv.QUOTE_ALL,dialect="excel")
            get_val = oneObject.getX(currentFrameIndex)
            for  humanPos in get_val:
                wr.writerow(humanPos)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not accumulate your sub-arrays and then use `np.savetxt` to write to CSV just once?

```
arrs = []
for currentFrameIndex in listOfFrameIndices:  # Demonstrative only.
    arrs.append(oneObject.getX(currentFrameIndex))
# Or,
# arrs = np.array([oneObject.getX(c) for c in listOfFrameIndices])

np.savetxt('file.csv', np.array(arrs), delimiter=',')
```